# Git workflow for WordPress theme development - with shared test server

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I am really scratching my head here, we want to implement Git into our workflow, as a relatively small team where it is usually one dev to a project we have not really seen the need to implement it.

However as we get larger we want that version control and more of a set process to how we work.

The issue I am having is, in WordPress we have our theme files in a Git repo on github.com which is fine.

We then have publicly accessible development website that sites on a webserver for the client/internal people to see.

We can pull the repo locally to our individual machinesand work on it no problem, sass and files are compiled and uploaded automatically to the test website, which is fine.

However, if a second dev needs to jump on this project, we are both amending .scss files independently of each other on our own machines, and the resulting style.css on each of our machines will upload to the test website and overwrite each other as we go.

So the next logical step for me was to have a fully local copy of the test site with all WordPress files and database for each dev to work on.

This creates a new problem, when I come to upload some code to the public facing test site, if another dev has pushed their changes it means we will then have to merge databases as there will be conflicting IDs and even have to merge some WordPress files such as the uploads folders. I am not really sure how that process would work without breaking everything. It also creates another step we have to complete in that when making a change it isn't automatically uploaded to the test web server. We would have to merge database and files quite often.

The "cheating" way around all of this was to clone the repo to Google Drive, both devs work on that (rarely on the same files and we are in the same room so thats not a huge issue). As we save styles it compiles and uploads fine, everyones changes are in there. However as I thought might happen, we are starting to get weird things happen in git with say 100 "newly" created files showing up to be staged (they are not new) and other oddities resulting in frequent re-cloning.

So with that I am stumped. How can I get this workflow working smoothly? I am open to any ideas! Thanks

Comment: There are many solutions to your problem. Have you considered using Git branches?

Comment: @JohnHanley Hi John, can you explain how branches would solve the need for all changes to files to be uploaded to one central test site that is accessible publicly? And all merge without issue?

Comment: Branches would allow you to work on your changes without the other developer affecting you. Once you are finished with your set of changes, you would merge them into main/master. I think your question is almost off-topic because you are asking for opinions/recommendations on how to do things. Each developer environment is different, so the best way **depends**. My guess is your knowledge of Git is limited. That is best solved by studying the documentation and lots of practice. There are numerous tutorials on branching and how to integrate multiple developers.

Comment: @JohnHanley I think you are misunderstanding, I know exactly how Git works,  and how branches work. What they do not solve is how I can have multiple devs pushing to a singular public facing development environment. Each dev has their own database / filesystem and these would have to be merged.